# Assign std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> to another std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, unique-ptr

I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` and I am assigning this to a second vector of the same type.

I am getting this compiler error:

```
/opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:324:18: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = MyClass; _Dp = std::default_delete<MyClass>]'
        *__result = *__first;
```

Is this because in order to do the assignment, I need to define a move assignment operator for `MyClass`? The class only contains a couple of unordered_maps, a set and a couple of primitives. No pointer members.

Comment: Use `std::move()` at level of the `std::vector` instead . `std::unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor as required from `std::vector`'s assignment operator.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks! If you leave this as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot copy-assign a vector of `std::unique_ptr` elements to another, because you cannot copy `std::unique_ptr` itself. It is unique!

No operations defined on your `MyClass` can change this fact.

You can move from such a vector, though - but that means the original vector will no longer hold those `std::unique_ptr` elements.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm going to give it to the person who left a comment as they beat you by about 30 seconds! Thank you for the answer though. I have up-voted.

Comment: @user997112 no worries :)

Comment: @user997112 You can accept this answer. I won't go and complain (and won't write another answer).

Comment: @user997112 A comment is easier to write than an answer. 30 seconds is unfair

Answer (score 3):

`unique_ptr`, as the name suggests, is not copyable. Only one instance can exist. As a result, you can't copy a vector containing `unique_ptr` elements, since they can't be copied from one vector to another. You can only move one vector to another:

```
dest_vector = std::move(src_vector);
```

`src_vector` can't be used after that (other than moving something new into it.) All the elements it contains have moved into `dest_vector`.

If you actually want copies, then use `shared_ptr` instead. Each copy will still manage the same pointer and will keep track of how many copies exist. The managed pointer will *only* be deleted once all `shared_ptr` copies have been destroyed.